# How to update a pointer member variable in C++

Tags: c++

This is the rough outline of my code. I've left out some details so let me know if you need more context.

```cpp
class A;
class B;

class C {
    public:
        C(int dat, int idx) {
            data = dat;
            i = idx;
        }

    friend class A;
    friend class B;

    private:
        int data;
        int i;

};

class A {
    public:

        void insert(int dat, int idx) {
            c = new C(dat, idx);
            // ... other operations to place it
        }

        // I have the correct destructor, etc..

        // function that returns an address to a specific instance of a dynamically allocated C
        C* getPointer(int dat) const {
            return getPointer(dat); // a call to an internal function 
            // omitted for simplicity because this works
        }

    private:
        C* c;
};

class B {

    public:
        B() {
            size = 5;
            arr = new D[size];
        }

        // I have the correct destructor, etc..

        C* getPtr(int idx) {
            return(arr[idx].X);
        }

        void setPtr(C*& oldPtr, C* newPtr) {
            oldPtr = newPtr;
        }

    private:
        struct D{
            int d;
            C* X;

            D() {
                d = 0;
                X = nullptr;
            }
        };
        D* arr;
        int size;
};


int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    // index is a value returned from an insert function in class B
    // dat is a value to find which address should be returned of the objects in class A

    a.setPtr(b.getPtr(index), a.getPointer(dat));

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote a function (`getPointer(int dat)` in class `A`) that returns the address of an instance of the dynamically allocated object of class `C`. So, how do I update `X` to point at this address instead of null?

I've tried many different ways and currently (what I thought was the most promising) was the `setPtr()` function in class `B`. It correctly changes the address `X` is pointing to once, but when I call any other functions its value is back to `nullptr`.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly wrote `getPtr(int idx)` (if I understand your spec. correctly). Now, the return value is `C*` there, which is not `C*&` or `C**`, so it won't be updated if you change the result afterwards - think of it as a `return i;` won't expose `int i;` member if return type is `int`.

So either:

- you need to change the return type of `getPtr(int idx)` and then `setPtr()` is not really needed;
- or you can build both of these in `setPtr()` as:

```
void setPtr(int idx, C* newPtr) {
    arr[idx].X = newPtr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That makes a lot of sense. Also quick question, if I write this function in `class B`, how do I get it to actually change the values? `void changeIdx(int idx, int newIdx) { arr[idx].X->i = newIdx; }`. Sorry for all the questions. I'm new to using references and pointers and I would like to understand their behaviour.

Comment: @Marg Don't try to do everything in one function - even `setPtr()` is a borderline for that -, you can simply add the change method to `C`. Note, since you store ptrs, result will be observable through all pointers pointing to the same object (if there are multiple).